# How to change the default subject line for SNS in Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I have setup a rule in cloudwatch to monitor Glue ETL. In the state change I am sending a notification to SNS. I have modified the input transformer to get a custom body of the email but not getting how to change the subject line of the email . It still giving the default "**AWS Notification Message**"

My Input transformer :

```
{"state":"$.detail.state"}

"The JOB has changed state to <state>."
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Lambda function—rather than the Amazon SNS topic—as a target for the CloudWatch Events rule. Then, configure the Lambda function to publish a custom message to the Amazon SNS topic when triggered by the CloudWatch Events rule.

Documented here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-sns-email-for-cloudwatch-events/

Answer (score 1):

**Transformer** (no way Jose)
As far as I can tell there is currently no way to control the email subject with a transformer. Typically you will control the notification body for a rule through the transformer which modifies the input json message (e.g. in the case of a build https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html#sample-build-notifications-ref ). Based on what I see in the documentation this only modifies part of the body embedded between the header and the footer of the email payload.

**JSON** (also not possible)
1. Since all notifications are generated with an API call with json payload you can experiment and configure. Using the CLI you can specify a json format using --message-structure attribute. However the subject is not part of the json payload itself and is sent as a separate parameter "--subject" (see example below) you won't be able to configure that unless they either modify the UI or the json payload.
2.In order to exercise greater control over your output you might have to use JSON (select "Constant (JSON text)") which is documented for mobile messaging https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-custommessage.html but not very well for HTTP https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html but decent for the CLI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/publish.html
3. You can go to the console https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/ and click on "Publish a Message" which allows you to specify a subject. Notice that there is a "JSON message generator" but that's only for the body.

**Coding Workaround** (possible ...kinda)
If you feel really determined you can explore a workaround: look at the API and figure out what call is equivalent to sending a call which includes a subject. Create a lambda function that executes that call. From the rule invoke the lambda :-) and you are done. If there is will, there is a way...

Notes:

aws sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:652499160872:DP-Build --message-structure json --subject "Test Build subject" --message "{ \"default\":\"Foo\", \"email\":\"Bar\"}"

According to the docs there is a "Subject" key you can pass as a parameter:

> Blockquote

**Subject**
The Subject parameter specified when the notification was published to the topic. Note that this is an optional parameter. If no Subject was specified, then this name/value pair does not appear in this JSON document.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

set "detail-type":"Glue ETL State-change Notification"
you might need to look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html

Comment: If I change the detail-type it stopped sending the notification

Comment: Can you be more specific with this answer? Thank you